# using coffee-script with compass project

Tags: coffeescript, rubygems, compass-sass

hi am creating project using compass(gem) and also trying to use coffee script along with compass. I installed coffee-script `gem` but now how do i include it in compass project. Is there any way to change `config.rb` file for run coffee-script ? like

```
css_dir = "attr/css"
sass_dir = "attr/sass"
images_dir = "attr/images"
javascripts_dir = "attr/js"
```

as like

```
coffee-script_dir = "attr/coffee"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that those are not supported to just work with each other. You could create a script which compiles both at once or you could just use 2 instances of cmd/terminal and "watch" both compass and coffee project. Compass: `compass watch` and CoffeeScript: `coffee ... --watch`.

If you're using Visual Studio, try [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench). There should also be similar tools/plugins for other ides.

Comment: i installed coffee-script gem but the error showing now 'coffee' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.and how do i compile and were should i place the coffee and its output directory

Comment: I'm not sure how it's with gem because on coffeescript webpage there's an example with nodejs. About the other question, it all depends on your preferences. I don't think that it's strictly defined how to place it.